# Jackson Json to POJO mapping

Tags: java, android, arrays, jackson, android-volley

Getting started with Jackson for the first time, I am having issues with mapping JSON data with java classes. The JSON structure is as follow:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "all_tags": [
    {
      "id": 14,
      "term_name": "Term 1",
      "category_details": [
        {
          "category_ID": 21,
          "category_name": "Category Name",
          "category_count": 1,
          "category_image": "...202x300.jpg"
        },
        {
          "category_ID": 19,
          "category_name": "Category Sample",
          "category_count": 3,
          "category_image": "...202x300.jpg"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 17,
      "term_name": "Term 2",
      "category_details": [
        {
          "category_ID": 20,
          "category_name": "Category Sample Again",
          "category_count": 1,
          "category_image": "....200x300.jpg"
        }
      ]
    },
    .......
  ]
}
```

I used [Jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) website to generate [CategoryDetail.java](http://pastebin.com/raw/7mGXtcD5) , [AllTag.java](http://pastebin.com/raw/UZWDCjbx), [Response.java](http://pastebin.com/raw/XJpe4kpV) POJO classes.

Because I am accessing JSON online I used volley to make requests:

```
        mRequestQueue = JacksonNetwork.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        mRequestQueue.add(new JacksonRequest<AllTag>(Request.Method.GET,
        "http://example.com/file.json",
        new JacksonRequestListener<AllTag>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(AllTag response, int statusCode, VolleyError error) {
                if (response != null) {
                    // I am not sure how to parse the JSON 
                    // and map the data to POJO 
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred while parsing the data! Stack trace follows:");
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public JavaType getReturnType() {
                return SimpleType.construct(AllTag.class);
            }
        })
);
```

I read the [documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) but I have no idea how to map the JSON data to the classes so I can loop and retreive the data later. Really appreciate if someone with Jackson knowledge send me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to jackson to read snakecase and also one more class reponse

```
public class Response {
    String status;
    List<AllTags> allTags;
    //setter getter
    // constructor
 }
```

update request

```
        mRequestQueue = JacksonNetwork.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    mRequestQueue.add(new JacksonRequest<Response>(Request.Method.GET,
    "http://example.com/file.json",
    new JacksonRequestListener<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response, int statusCode, VolleyError error) {
            if (response != null) {
                // response.getAllTags() loop here
                // I am not sure how to parse the JSON 
                // and map the data to POJO 
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred while parsing the data! Stack trace follows:");
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public JavaType getReturnType() {
            return SimpleType.construct(Response.class);
        }
    })
 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am using [this extension](https://github.com/spothero/volley-jackson-extension) so I dont think I need a response class?

Comment: You need a class structure that exactly represent your json object. Check this https://github.com/spothero/volley-jackson-extension/blob/master/Demo/VolleyJacksonDemo/src/main/java/com/spothero/volleyjacksondemo/DateReturnType.java and http://date.jsontest.com/ for reference provide in volley-jackson-ext response

Comment: so the class structure that I posted in the question is incorrect? I followed the same example but that example is very simple and does not cover how to store object arrays.

Comment: So you have AllTags but this represent "all_tags" each element not the root json obj, which has two field status(string) and all_tags(array). Also configure if not jackson to read properties as snake_case, by default it is set to camelCase.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, after that how do I map the json data?

Comment: You donot need to jackson will do that, you get pojo deserialized from json